# What happens when an MSMQ transaction isn't commited/aborted?

Tags: transactions, msmq

Say I have a transactional queue.

```
var msgQ = MessageQueue.Create(@".\$private\Orders", True)
msgQ.DefaultPropertiesToSend.Recoverable = true;
```

Now say I go to consume a message off the queue...

```
var msgTx = New MessageQueueTransaction();
msgTx.Begin();
var msg = msgQ.Receive(msgTx)
```

... **and then the machine goes down before a commit or abort can take place.**

What happens to the message I tried to receive?

Answer (score 0):

As stated in [the documentation for Receive](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xc8teys8%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

> Because this method is called on a transactional queue, the message
>   that is received would be returned to the queue if the transaction is
>   aborted. The message is not permanently removed from the queue until
>   the transaction is committed.

Comment: What if a commit/abort never actually happens?  Does an abort implicitly based on some criteria?  If so, what are those criteria (or where can I find the documentation)?

Comment: The transaction will timeout. Doesn't seem to be any documentation, [@JohnBreakwell's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5905569/43846) to [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5903538/messagequeuetransaction-timeout) alludes to it though.

Comment: MSMQ should detect the application has gone away and clean up by restoring the message to it's original state in the queue. Non-transactional messages would be destroyed.

Comment: @JohnBreakwell, does that happen based upon a timeout, heartbeat or some other mechanism?  Is it configurable at all?  Thanks for chiming in.

Comment: Good questions but I have no answers. I may have something in my archives that explains how MSMQ knows but no promises.